# Difference between Completely Non Trivial Dependency and Non Trivial Dependency

Tags: database

What is the difference between Non Trivial Functional Dependencies and Completely non trivial Dependencies?

As per as my search i found a confusing difference between the two. I visited http://www.tutorialspoint.com/dbms/database_normalization.htm

According to this, 
**Non-trivial**: If an FD X → Y holds where Y is not subset of X, then it is called non-trivial FD.

**Completely non-trivial**: If an FD X → Y holds where x intersect Y = Φ, is said to be completely non-trivial FD.

Being Y not subset of X and X intersect Y = Φ. Don't they point towards the same.

Example: X={1,2,3,4}, Y={5,6}
here we see Y is not subset of X and also Y intersect X = Φ.

Then, My question is what is the reason behind saying difference between non trivial dependency and Completely non Trivial Dependency? If there is any difference, then what is that exact one. Please suggest me. I googled it, but not found the satisfactory one.

Comment: I've been in the database field for 30 years. I've never heard the term *completely nontrivial functional dependency*. If I were you, I'd pick a different tutorial.

Comment: Yes sir, I was also confused to see the difference but found on the tutorialspoint website, that's why asked here on stackoverflow. So that i may get the proper solution here.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the following case:

P = { R1, R2 } and Q = { R1, R3 }

Then,

P->Q is non-trivial.

P->Q isn't completely non-trivial. (because the intersection of P and Q is = { R1 }

Answer (score 0):

Don't think of X and Y as sets directly.They are attributes of a table. What that means is that :

when AB->BC then it is Non-Trivial FD(Here u can see that B is common in both sides. So that doesn't happens in complete  non-trivial)

i.e.
when AB->CD here AB intersection CD is none unlike in the above case.This is the basic difference between Non-trivial and Complete non-trivial.